# Embedding framework in mac app bundle

Tags: ios, macos

I create a requirementCheck.bundle project for Mac installer,  and then create a framework and drag it to the bundle.

I think this may because that i use installer app to run withe bundle, since i get the value `[[NSBundle mainBundle]executablePath]` from the bundle project when installer is running, it's `/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer`.
So maybe the run search path is based from this location.

**The build settings for this framework is as below:**

[image]

**The build phrase of the bundle project is as below:**

[image]

**The build setting of the bundle project is as below:**

[image]

After that, i make package with this bundle and run the installer. Then error happens when enter this bundle. It says: `Error loading /var/folders/d5/ydvs_pts06l_v4pltvtd80880000gn/T/com.apple.install.AifpVAae/TMRequiredChecking.bundle/Contents/MacOS/TMRequiredChecking:  dlopen(/var/folders/d5/ydvs_pts06l_v4pltvtd80880000gn/T/com.apple.install.AifpVAae/TMRequiredChecking.bundle/Contents/MacOS/TMRequiredChecking, 265): Library not loaded: @rpath/XXXXX.framework/Versions/A/XXXXX
  Referenced from: /var/folders/d5/ydvs_pts06l_v4pltvtd80880000gn/T/com.apple.install.AifpVAae/TMRequiredChecking.bundle/Contents/MacOS/TMRequiredChecking
  Reason: image not found`

I have checked the framework ins copied to TMRequiredChecking.bundle/Contents/Frameworks` folder, and i tried so many different paths (@executable_path../Frameworks, @loader_path/Frameworks)  for the key "Dynamic Library Install Name Base" of the framework project. None of them worked. So anyone can tell me how to make this framework be found by the bundle project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the solution for this case.Refer to the @loader_path description of  this link [Here](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath)

I set the "Dynamic Install Name Base" of the framework project to `@loader_path../Frameworks` and then set "Runpath Search Paths" of the bundle project to `@loader_path../Frameworks`. Then everythings works fine.